How to connect edges in image using OpenCV?
I have a binary image which includes some kind of rectangle shapes where only edges are fully visible. I want to join missing lines and make complete rectangles. How this can be achieved using OpenCV.

My targeted result is like below:


you need to detect what orientation each corner has. then I'd try to pair the top-left corners with the bottom-right corners using the other two corners as helpers. Once you know the pairings just draw 4 lines

@Elerium115 Thank you for your comment. Could you share some code snippet if possible? How to detect orientation of the corners?

Sorry, this is something you will need to implement. You can use convolution with different kernels. Some kernels are horizontal line detectors, others are vertical line detectors. You can create your own kernel that detects L shapes. Then mirror the kernel Horizontally and vertically to detect all 4 types of corners. Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)

Using cv2.houghLinesP

find those corner symbols. identify the orientation of each. look for suitable matches along the expected directions. only associate to the nearest match along axis. associate. repeat until all associated or no possible associations. you're left with a graph of multiple connected components, each being a 4-cycle hopefully, or maybe not.

This is not a simple task to accomplish.  You need identify the corners of the bounding box in the image, then match them together before drawing the rest of the rectangles.  The first part is normally done using a convolution.  There are several libraries that handle this: pattern_match from scikit-image is a good start.
However in this particular case, the corners are single valued and one-pixel wide and tall.  You can brute force finding the corners by sweeping a window over your image array and matching what a corner would look like.  That will find the locations of the corners.
Then you need to match up the corners that belong together.  The top-value of the top-left and top-right corners should be very close; the left-value for the top-left and bottom-left corners should be very close; etc.
Here is what I described above in two steps.  First we collect the image data and convert it to a numpy array.
import cv2
import io
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import requests
from collections import namedtuple

# first collect our data and turn it into a numpy array
res = requests.get('https://i.sstatic.net/cLDfS.png')
img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(res.content))
img_arr = np.array(img)

# create objects to organize the data 
CornerCollection = namedtuple('CornerCollection', ['tls', 'trs', 'brs', 'bls'])
BoundingBox = namedtuple('BoundingBox', ['tl', 'tr', 'br', 'bl'])

Add function that steps through image array and looks for an exact match to the corners.
def find_corners(img: np.array) -> CornerCollection:
    """Finds the corners outlines in a mono-tone image."""
    top_left = np.array([[1,1],[1,0]])
    top_right = np.array([[1,1],[0,1]])
    bot_right = np.array([[0,1],[1,1]])
    bot_left = np.array([[1,0],[1,1]])

    tl_corners = []
    tr_corners = []
    br_corners = []
    bl_corners = []

    window_iter = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(np.array(img), (2,2))
    for i, row_view in enumerate(window_iter):
        for j, view in enumerate(row_view):
            if (view == top_left).all():
                tl_corners.append((i, j))
            if (view == top_right).all():
                tr_corners.append((i, j + 1))
            if (view == bot_right).all():
                br_corners.append((i + 1, j + 1))
            if (view == bot_left).all():
                bl_corners.append((i, j + 1))
    return CornerCollection(tl_corners, tr_corners, br_corners, bl_corners)

crnr_col = find_corners(img_arr)

Here we iterate through each top-left corner and find the best match for the other corners.  This returns a list of BoundingBox objects.
def merge_corners(cc: CornerCollection) -> list[BoundingBox]:
    boxes = []
    trs: list = cc.trs.copy()
    bls: list = cc.bls.copy()
    brs: list = cc.brs.copy()
    for (tl_i, tl_j) in cc.tls:
        best_tr = min(trs, key=lambda ij: abs(ij[0] - tl_i))
        best_bl = min(bls, key=lambda ij: abs(ij[1] - tl_j))
        best_br = min(brs, key=lambda ij: abs(ij[0] - tl_i) + abs(ij[1] - tl_j))
        trs.remove(best_tr)
        bls.remove(best_bl)
        brs.remove(best_br)
        boxes.append(BoundingBox((tl_i, tl_j), best_tr, best_br, best_bl))
    return boxes

bboxes = merge_corners(crnr_col)
bboxes
# returns:
[BoundingBox(tl=(9, 534), tr=(9, 545), br=(41, 545), bl=(41, 534)),
 BoundingBox(tl=(57, 672), tr=(57, 689), br=(80, 689), bl=(80, 672)),
 BoundingBox(tl=(77, 322), tr=(77, 340), br=(127, 340), bl=(127, 322)),
 BoundingBox(tl=(107, 849), tr=(107, 872), br=(143, 872), bl=(143, 849)),
 BoundingBox(tl=(132, 758), tr=(132, 794), br=(268, 794), bl=(268, 758)),
 BoundingBox(tl=(160, 916), tr=(160, 971), br=(298, 971), bl=(298, 916)),
 BoundingBox(tl=(169, 524), tr=(169, 539), br=(186, 539), bl=(186, 524)),
 BoundingBox(tl=(199, 581), tr=(199, 640), br=(325, 640), bl=(325, 581)),
 BoundingBox(tl=(244, 1155), tr=(244, 1191), br=(343, 1191), bl=(343, 1155))]

Using the bboxes, you can add lines from tl to tr to br to bl and back to tl to make the rectangles or use the cv2.rectangle function.
import cv2

for bbox in bboxes:
    cv2.rectangle(img_arr, bbox.tl[::-1], bbox.br[::-1], color=1, thickness=1)



I thought I'd throw "my" approach in the pot as well. I didn't see the answer by James yet when I wrote my comment. My approach is very similar, adding some directional constraints. I also assume that the corners sit exactly in line with each other, i.e. with no pixels of shift off the axis they form.
Approach:

using the "Hit-and-Miss Transform", find those corner marks, grouped by which corner they indicate
find closest matching corner in each direction

This will find all the boxes if all the angles match.
I'll present two approaches to associate nodes into rectangles. The first one is more "pedestrian", going around the rectangle in a fixed order. The second one builds a graph, so it can handle missing corners a little more elegantly.
I do not handle the case of a rectangle having just two corners. If they're diagonally opposite of each other, this could be recovered. I don't do that. It would just require looking in the right direction and considering the nearest corner... but this would have to make sure to not catch a corner that actually belongs to a complete rectangle.

# hit-miss-transform

kernel = np.array([
    [-1, -1, -1],
    [-1, +1, +1],
    [-1, +1, -1]
], dtype=np.int8)

def find_corners(im, kernel):
    res = cv.morphologyEx(im, cv.MORPH_HITMISS, kernel)
    coords = cv.findNonZero(res)
    return coords.reshape((-1, 2)).tolist()

coords_tl = find_corners(im, kernel) # corner 1
coords_tr = find_corners(im, np.rot90(kernel, -1)) # corner 2
coords_br = find_corners(im, np.rot90(kernel, -2)) # corner 3
coords_bl = find_corners(im, np.rot90(kernel, -3)) # corner 4


First variant/alternative:
# finding nearest corners in a certain direction
# dx and dy either lock that axis down or allow candidates in that direction

def closest_in_direction(x, y, dx, dy, coords):
    candidates = [
        i for i, (xx, yy) in enumerate(coords)
        if (((xx - x) * dx >= 0) if dx != 0 else (xx == x))
        and (((yy - y) * dy >= 0) if dy != 0 else (yy == y))
    ]

    if not candidates:
        return None

    def distance_predicate(i):
        xx, yy = coords[i]
        return max(abs(xx - x), abs(yy - y))

    return min(candidates, key=distance_predicate)

# assembling boxes from corners

boxes = []
while len(coords_tl) > 0:
    x0, y0 = coords_tl.pop()
    x1 = y1 = None
    # looking for x1, y1 which is corner 3, diagonal to corner 1

    if (i2 := closest_in_direction(x0, y0, dx=1, dy=0, coords=coords_tr)) is not None:
        x1, y0_ = coords_tr.pop(i2)
        assert y0_ == y0

    if (i4 := closest_in_direction(x0, y0, dx=0, dy=1, coords=coords_bl)) is not None:
        x0_, y1 = coords_bl.pop(i4)
        assert x0_ == x0

    if (x1 is not None) and (y1 is not None):
        if (i3 := closest_in_direction(x1, y1, dx=0, dy=0, coords=coords_br)) is not None:
            coords_br.pop(i3)
        else:
            print("BR corner not found, inferred")

        boxes.append((x0, y0, x1, y1))

assert len(coords_tl) == 0
assert len(coords_tr) == 0
assert len(coords_br) == 0
assert len(coords_bl) == 0

# draw the boxes

pad = 5
canvas = cv.cvtColor(im, cv.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
for box in boxes:
    (x0, y0, x1, y1) = box
    (x0, y0, x1, y1) = (x0 - pad, y0 - pad, x1 + pad, y1 + pad)
    cv.rectangle(canvas, (x0, y0), (x1, y1), color=(0, 255, 0))



Here is the second variant/alternative that constructs a graph and extracts connected components. It starts from the corners and their direction information.
Building the graph:

have a list of nodes
consider all pairs
check if there should be an edge between a pair, or not

Finding connected components:

pick any unvisited node (they're all unvisited initially)
find its neighbors, find their neighbors, ... until you have them all
mark them as visited
repeat

# (x, y, dx, dy) # dx,dy suggest edges in specific direction
nodes = \
    [ (x,y, +1, +1) for (x,y) in coords_tl ] + \
    [ (x,y, -1, +1) for (x,y) in coords_tr ] + \
    [ (x,y, -1, -1) for (x,y) in coords_br ] + \
    [ (x,y, +1, -1) for (x,y) in coords_bl ]

def construct_edges(nodes):
    edges = set()
    # run through all pairings, test for edgability, maybe create edge
    for i in range(len(nodes)-1):
        for j in range(i+1, len(nodes)):
            (ax, ay, adx, ady) = nodes[i]
            (bx, by, bdx, bdy) = nodes[j]
            dx = ax - bx
            dy = ay - by

            if ((ay == by) and (adx * bdx < 0) and (dx * adx < 0)) \
            or ((ax == bx) and (ady * bdy < 0) and (dy * ady < 0)):
                edges.add((i, j))

    return edges

edges = construct_edges(nodes)

All those single edges, drawn in arbitrary order, already look like you got rectangles in the right places... but there aren't any real rectangles. It's just the edges of them.
def get_connected_components(nodes, edges):
    components = set()
    # set of sets, theoretically, frozenset etc...
    # since our components are supposed to be contours, I'll give them order
    # they'll be ordered TL, TR, BR, BL. nodes are already ordered in this way.

    visited = np.zeros(len(nodes), dtype=bool)

    while not visited.all():
        i = np.argmin(visited) # find an unvisited node (min: false < true)
        component = {i}
        visited[i] = True
        # add transitively until all neighbors are visited.
        iterate = True # (component was extended, potentially more neighbors to visit)
        while iterate:
            iterate = False
            for u,v in edges:
                if (u in component) ^ (v in component):
                    component |= {u, v}
                    visited[u] = True
                    visited[v] = True
                    iterate = True

        components.add(tuple(sorted(component))) # a set, theoretically, but eh

    return components

components = get_connected_components(nodes, edges)

Each of those is a list of node indices. Just look the nodes up and collect their coordinates. If you're sure all the boxes have four corners, then you can just draw the edges in order. If you aren't sure, get min and max of the coordinates along X and Y, and use that for a rectangle.
for component in components:
    coords = np.array([nodes[k][:2] for k in component])
    x0 = coords[:,0].min()
    x1 = coords[:,0].max()
    y0 = coords[:,1].min()
    y1 = coords[:,1].max()

    cv.rectangle(
        img=canvas,
        pt1=(x0 - pad, y0 - pad),
        pt2=(x1 + pad, y1 + pad),
        color=(0, 255, 0),
    )


(looks the same, it's supposed to, except for the node-to-node lines)
