OpenCV code fail to detect overlapping rectangles in an image
I am using OpenCV to detect rectangles in an image based on their color. The code works well for non-overlapping rectangles, but it fails to detect overlapping rectangles.
Here's code I am using
image_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)  
lower_blue = np.array([110, 50, 50])  
upper_blue = np.array([130, 255, 255])  
mask = cv2.inRange(image_hsv, lower_blue, upper_blue)  
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)  
  
for index, contour in enumerate(contours):  
    epsilon = 0.02 * cv2.arcLength(contour, True)  
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contour, epsilon, True)  
  
    if len(approx) == 4:  
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(approx)  
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

Overlapping rectangles are either not detected at all or are detected as a single merged shape. This is problematic because I need to individually detect and crop each rectangle, even if they overlap.
I’ve Tried:

Adjusting the Contour Approximation: I tried tweaking the epsilon parameter in cv2.approxPolyDP to various values, but it didn't help in detecting overlapping rectangles.
Changing the Mask Range: I experimented with different HSV ranges to ensure the mask correctly covers the rectangles, but this didn't resolve the overlapping issue
Contour Retrieval Mode: I also tried different contour retrieval modes (like cv2.RETR_TREE and cv2.RETR_LIST), but it didn't improve the detection of overlapping rectangles.

For eg. Sample Input Image

Outputs I get



Not getting the overlapping one's.

bad approach, I'd say. show us mask as an image. I mean, you should look at it, but we'd like to see too. when you look at it, you might see why findContours won't find what you're looking for.

since you have straight lines, this method may work in your case.

based on the identified joints, you'd want to find those that are corner joints, and then recover rectangles from those. I did connect such corner joints here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78365899/how-to-connect-edges-in-image-using-opencv/78368150#78368150

@Christoph Rackwitz. OP wants to detect overlapped. Just like three images to crop it

I was already aware of that. my comment builds on the comment by Yunus.


Overlapping rectangles are either not detected at all or are detected
as a single merged shape. This is problematic because I need to
individually detect and crop each rectangle, even if they overlap.

Your problem can be fixed.
On line 12, change this:
cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL # It will not detect some parts of blue.
to:
cv2.RETR_TREE #It will detect overlap.
On line 18, change this:
if len(approx) == 4: 

to:
if contours: #So we going to use cv2.drawContours
Comment out from line 19 to 23.
Add cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3) on line 25.
Snippet minor change:
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load the image
img = cv2.imread('i.png')

# convert to grayscale
image_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)  
lower_blue = np.array([110, 50, 50])  
upper_blue = np.array([130, 255, 255])  
mask = cv2.inRange(image_hsv, lower_blue, upper_blue)  
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)  
  
for index, contour in enumerate(contours):  
    epsilon = 0.02 * cv2.arcLength(contour, True)  
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contour, epsilon, True)  
  
    if contours:  
        #(x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(approx)  
    #cv2.rectangle(img,
                  #(x,y),(x+w,y+h),
                  #(0,255,0),
                  #2)
        
        
        cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)

cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

Screenshot:

There is another way to use movseevent instead of cv2.drawContours. If you want that.

this code completely disables all filtering. it does not actually find rectangles. it merely draws all contours, indiscriminately, and repeatedly. this cannot have helped anyone. I cannot imagine a justification for the upvote this answer has received. the contours themselves are certainly NOT the answer, nor is RETR_TREE

@Christoph Rackwitz. OP merely drew the blue rectangle that OP selected.

How will this crop out the images of rectangles

it will not. the user Supra is known for posting things that make no sense. it may be unkind to say this about another user but it's true and you should be made aware of this.

@spd. If you want to select a desired object, then you use mouse events to crop out the images of rectangles.

except this answer doesn't extract the desired rectangles. assuming (!) that OP restores (comment-in) the pieces of his own original code that do try to extract rectangles, this only works in this picture because the extent of the biggest CC piece of each rectangle coincides with the desired rectangle. if you had two rects intersecting like a cross, this code would fail because that shape is split into 5 parts, and no bounding rect coincides with either of the original rects.

I am tired of having to refute these low quality contributions of yours.
